# What prevents a reviewer from stealing the idea?

Tags: journals, peer-review

The reviewer has the copy for manuscript and they are generally top notch in the field in which the paper was written. What prevents the reviewer from exploiting his/her power? As in, rejecting it and publishing a slightly modified version himself?

I am new to this, so forgive me it is a foolish question.